# 1986 G30 Motorhome

Tags: electrical, chevrolet, lights

I just replaced my parking lights. (the ones on the top front of the motor home. I got three of them replaced and they were working.  Then when I got to the fourth one my tail light fuse started blowing.  It has continuity through all the parking lights.  The multimeter showed that the tail light fuse was pulling 12.4 volts.....so what should it be pulling and where should I look next for the problem ??

Comment: 12.4v is nominal battery voltage. It just means the fuse socket is getting power. When you say "pulling" that implies electrical current, which is what causes fuses to blow. If it's a 10 Amp fuse, for example, it should blow when current draw or current 'pull' exceeds about 10 Amps.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a bad replacement bulb that is shorted. If you have an old, working bulb try that to see if it still blows the fuse. If an old bulb does not cause the fuse to blow (and the light works), then it was the new bulb.

You could also try swapping one of the other new bulbs in that same spot.